# Let f : R → R be a function such that | f(x) - f(y)| ≤ | sin x - sin y|, for each x,y Є R .....

Tags: calculus

Let **f** : $\Bbb R$  → $\Bbb R$ be a function with the property | **f**(x) - **f**(y)| ≤ | sin x - sin y| , for every real numbers x,y.

1. Prove that that there exists an unique real number c such that **f**(c) = c.
2. Consider the sequence ($x_{n}$) with $x_{0}$=0 and $x_{n+1}$= **f**($x_{n}$) for every positive integer n. Prove that sequence converges and its limit is c.

So far I have come up with this: since sin x = 0 implies x= n$\pi$, where n is an integer, we get that **f**(n$\pi$)=f(0). Since the function sin is periodic with period 2$\pi$, we obtain | **f**(x+2$\pi$) - **f**(x)|  ≤ | sin(x+2$\pi$) - sin x|, which is equivalent to **f**(x+2$\pi$) = **f**(x), for every real x, so the function **f** has period 2$\pi$.I've also thought about restricting to the interval [0,2$\pi$], since **f** is periodic, and apply Rolle's theorem on the intervals [0,$\pi$] and [$\pi$,2$\pi$], but I got nothing.

Comment: Since $\sin x -\sin y = \int_x^y \cos(t) dt$, you can show that for $x\ne y$, $|\sin x - \sin y| < |x-y|$. This gives uniqueness easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|f(x)-f(y)| \le |\sin x - \sin y| \le |x-y|$, we see that $f$ is continuous.

Since $|f(x)-f(0)| \le |\sin x| \le 1$, we see that $f$ is bounded.

It follows from the intermediate value theorem that the function $\phi(x) = f(x)-x$ must have at least one zero, that is $f$ has at least one fixed point.

Since $\sin x -\sin y = \int_x^y \cos(t) dt$, and $|\cos t| <1$ for ae. $t$, we see that if $x \neq y$, then
$|\sin x - \sin y| < |x-y|$. Consequently $f$ can only have one fixed point, since if $f(x)=x$, $f(y) = y$, then if $x\neq y$, we have
$|x-y|=|f(x)-f(y)| < |x-y|$, a contradiction.

Let $c$ denote the unique fixed point.

Now suppose $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$. We see from above that $x_n \in [f(0)-1,f(0)+1]$, which is compact. Let $\delta_n = |x_{n+1}-x_n|$, and if $\delta_n >0$, we see that $0 \le \delta_{n+1} < \delta_n \le 2$.

I need a technical estimate: Suppose $0 < \delta \le |x-y| \le \pi$, then 
$|\sin x - \sin y| \le (\operatorname{sinc} {\delta \over 2})|x-y|$.
Since $\sin x - \sin y = 2 \sin { x-y\over 2} \cos { x+y \over 2}$, then
$|\sin x-\sin y| \le 2 |\sin { x-y\over 2}| = 2 |\operatorname{sinc} {x - y \over 2} ||{x - y \over 2}| $. Since $\max_{t \in [\delta, \pi]} \operatorname{sinc} {t \over 2}  = \operatorname{sinc} {\delta \over 2}$, we obtain the desired result.

Returning to the proof, we have $\delta = \lim_n \delta_n = 0$.  To see this, suppose $\delta  >0$. Then the above shows that $\delta_{n+1} \le \operatorname{sinc} {\delta \over 2} \delta_n$, which gives a contradiction, hence $\delta = 0$, and so $\lim_n (f(x_n) - x_n) = 0$.

Since $x_n \in [f(0)-1,f(0)+1]$  is compact, we see that $x_{n}$ must have an accumulation point $x$, and we must have $f(x)-x = 0$, and so $x=c$ (since the fixed point is unique). It follows that $x_n \to c$.

Comment: Why the downvote? If there is something incorrect please let me know.

Comment: I did not downvote, but there are two things which are not quite clear to me: 1. On which domain are you using the intermediate value theorem? 2. Your argument for the strict inequality isn't quite transparent to me.

Comment: I think at the part where you established $\delta$ ≤ $\pi$, it should be $\delta_{n}$ instead, since $\delta$ is the limit itself. Anyway, that's a very nice proof, thank you very much!

Comment: @AlexanderSmith: We have $\delta_n \le 2$ from the second line above, the appearance of $\pi$ was unnecessary from a proof perspective.

Comment: @Roland: The domain is $\mathbb{R}$, since this is the domain of $f$. For strict inequality, I need to show that $|\int_x^y |\cos t|dt| < |x-y|$. We have $|\cos t| \le 1$ for all $t$, so we have (assume $x<y$) $\int_x^y (1-|\cos t|)dt \ge 0$. Since $x\neq y$, there must be a point $s \in [x,y]$ where $|\cos s| <1$, and so it must be true on some small subinterval. Hence we have $\int_x^y (1-|\cos t|)dt > 0$, which is the desired result.